# Boosting WIFI signal 20metres

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, home-networking, network-adapter, wifi-configuration

I have two properties in a street, around 20 metres apart and two other houses in between. Is it possible to boost the wifi siginal so I can use in both properties? What type of hardware would I need for this?

I was reading about extenders and boosters, but I am not sure if this is just useful for boosting to other rooms in the house?

Comment: How tall are your buildings, and how tall are the buildings in between?

Comment: I would ONLY solve this problem with commercial grade hardware. @grawity I'm sure all the buildings are the same height. And you're going to recommend a beam type of technology right? Aren't those normally commercial grade?

Comment: @Sickest: What do you mean by "commercial grade"?

Comment: @grawity Great question. The OP is asking for non-commercial grade hardware. aka Cheap hardware? I guess that really depends on what he thinks commercial grade is. But I look at commercial grade hardware as being something that isn't sold at a typical big box store like Best Buy (USA company). Something that isn't exactly user friendly. Or I guess hardware that you'd typically find in a commercial setting.

Comment: @Sickest Why are you arguing about an off-topic question?

Comment: First off, I wasn't arguing. I was having a conversation in regards to the question at hand. Secondly, this type of question gets asked hundreds, if not thousands of times a month on SU. Sometimes they get through the cracks because someone quickly answers and doesn't recommend a product specifically and the answer is acceptable.

Comment: The issue here is, when people ask questions to problems in which only a specific type of product can solve that problem. Just like this question. He's not literally asking for a specific product, he's asking (in my opinion) what type of product would solve his problem. For example, If someone says: I want to connect a computer to my router without using wifi. The obvious answer would be to say, get a network cable. But isn't that a product recommendation? Doesn't that network cable have a brand and part number? But it's not off topic because network cables are typically off brand?

Comment: The way I look at these types of questions, as long as a brand name or part number is not referenced, it shouldn't be considered a product recommendation. But I could be wrong, and probably am wrong. I'm sorry, I'm not trying to offend anyone. But just trying to help others get the help they need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible - ive done shots well over 1km and know others who have done shots over 10km.

**General Solution**

In this case, its likely to be comparitively trivial (albeit not cheap). You should get an AP and an AP client which can take external antennas, get apropriate outdoor antennas and mount them on the roofs if each building such that you can see one from the other. Id recommend a fairly low gain directional/panel antenna.

** Possible easier hacks*

Depending on the area (ie how many competing signals and where the signal needs to be pucjed up) you may be able to get away with a single decent outdoor AP. I live rurally, and have a single Ubiquity AP on the roof if my house which gives me in excess of 70 meters range, including a hothouse on the other side of a secondary unit, with full coverage in that unit as well.

Ubiquity gear is inexpensive and very high quality / excellent sensitivity, and well worth  the slight premium - especially compared to cheap SOHO routers/APs.

You might want to try mount 1 outdoor unit as an AP on the house with the Internet connectikn and see if that suffices. If not, get a second one configured as an APclient externally on the other house.

No doubt there are many to choose from but something like a Ubiquity Nanostation M2 should do you.